# error while compiling: "fatal error: cmocka.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated."

Tags: c

I was trying to write a basic unit test. But I am getting error while compiling it: "fatal error: cmocka.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated." Can anyone help me?

Comment: Retagged, as this has nothing to do with `c#`

Comment: What is your compile command? How did you include it in your source file?

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the file `cmocka.h` exists in the directory in which your compiler searchs the includes. The other details depends on your compiler, and eventually on your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

This error `No such file or directory compilation` is pretty self explanatory. You're trying to include `cmocka.h` and the compiler can't find it. So:

1) make sure you have that file somewhere. If you're on Linux you can search recursively for it in any directory you're in with something like `find . -name "cmocka.h"`, if you're on Windows I'm sure you can search using the file browser

2a) If you find/have it locally make sure you're including it correctly

`#include "cmocka.h"` rather than `#include <cmocka.h>` or if it's in a subdirectory make sure you're including the path in the build command or in the include.

2b) If you don't have it then you'll have to download it from somewhere, you should be able to [google for it like I did here](http://cmocka.cryptomilk.org/api/cmocka_8h_source.html) but make sure it's the right version you need.